# jquery validaton near the label itself

Tags: php, jquery

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
       if($('#usr_name').val()==''){
         alert('Enter Your Name!!!');
         $('#usr_name').focus();
         return false;
       }
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="label_left"><label>Name :</label></div>
<div class="text_right">
    <input type="text" name="usr_name" id="usr_name"  value=""  size="30" /><br  /><br  />
</div>
```

am using this format to validation in jquery. it is showing an alert message. but what i require is it has to place enter your name beside the label when it is not filled is it possible. if so how to do this. help me thanks.

Comment: search for jquery validation plugins, lot of them are available in net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search for jquery validation plugins, lot of them are available in net

Ref: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Demo : http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/validateform/ i have this link regarding this but when am adding this code in codeigniter in a continution page that is when clicking on continue button content div will be changing in that case this code is note working.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the source for jquery validation with example.

[Github source](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)
[all jquery validation Demo](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Create another div whose style contains display:none, beside/below/wherever the element you want to validate. If the validation fails, use jQuery's .show method to show the hidden warning.
for example:

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
          function validate() {
   if($('#usr_name').val()==''){
     $("#name_warning_id").show();
     $('#usr_name').focus();
     return false;
      }
   </script>
   <div class="label_left"><label>Name :</label></div>
<div class="text_right"><input type="text" name="usr_name" id="usr_name"  value=""  size="30" /><div class="some_warning_class" id="name_warning_id" style="display:none;background-color:#F4A83D">Enter Your Name</div><br  /><br  />
</div>
```

Comment: as you said we are giving it in a new div. but it is displaying first itself. what was the sollution for this.

Comment: sorry, set display:hidden should be display:none, in the style attribute of the warning div, have edited my answer. This means that the warning div wont take up any space, as opposed to setting the visibility to hidden which allows the hidden div to take up the room it normally would.